# eclipse 'hide view' while customizing perspective not coming into effect

Tags: eclipse, perspective

It's really frustating, that a simple customizing of perspective is not working. I had given it a try multiple times, but didn't get a solution yet.

Problem: Hide all the view in the java perspective and only show Console and Tasks.

Tried:
I'm aware of Windows Menu -> Perspective -> Customize Perspective ->> 4th Tab(Shortcuts) --> 2nd Dropdown (Views)
Here I select and deselect the views I need, but each time I open eclipse or switch perspectives I get back all the tons of views back again (Task List, problems, error log, javadoc, declarations, Outline, and what not...). I want to remove all the clutter from the screen. I am aware of the 'Save Perspective as' option in the same menu trail above, but that also does not have any effect.

Anyone gone through the same pain? How to make this work?

[image: eclipse customize perspective - show/hide view]

Note: I am on ubuntu 15.10 . Eclipse version : Mars

Answer (score 0):

That customize option only changes the 'Show View' menu not the actual open views.

If you actually close the views you don't want that should be remembered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I mis-interpretted. But it doesn't remember the last open views as well. Tried it.. Closed all the views and reopened, all clutter comes back again.

Comment: fyi... I am ubuntu 15.10, eclipse - Mars.